# How to get to know via command-line/adb where boot process hangs?

Tags: boot, crashes, system, command-line

## Question:

(How) is it possible to get to know via adb where exactly a booting-up android device is hanging?

## My problem/ background information:

I recently did changes on the automatic display brightness threshold settings, and while doing the device just did "reset" itself (rebootet), and is stuck with showing the boot animation.

I see that the automatic display brightness works.

I can connect with adb via USB and have full shell access.

Logcat also spits out a lot of things.

When I try to start `trebuchet` manually with `am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet`, I get

```
Error type 2
android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:100)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?` also appears when I try to play around with `am` in other ways.

So I deduce the device did not finish booting up and hangs somewhere. For fixing it, I first need to find out where. Then there might be a follow-up question how to understand and fix it, depending what the problem is.

I wiped dalvik cache and cache-partition from ClockWorkMod, after that it does the usual "optimizing apps", but when finished still does not complete booting and showing the boot animation.

I am not familiar with the Android boot process, is there any good information on it suitable for people familiar with the internals Unix boot process (Linux, `sysvinit`, `openrc`, in my case)? Is there a way to do a verbosely logged boot process?

## Device information:

It's a Sony sk17i (marketing name "Xperia mini pro"), running [Cyanogenmod 10.1-extended](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2048807) which is based on Android 4.1.2 and [nAa kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2214282) 2.6.32.60.

`getprop` and `uname` outputs:

- `getprop ro.build.version.release`: `4.1.2`
- `getprop ro.build.version.sdk`: `16`
- `getprop ro.product.model`: `Xperia Mini Pro`
- `uname -r`: `2.6.32.60-nAa-01`
- `getprop`:

  ```
  [BUILD_UTC_DATE]: [0]
  [com.qc.hardware]: [true]
  [com.qc.hdmi_out]: [false]
  [dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags]: [m=y]
  [dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit]: [48m]
  [dalvik.vm.heapsize]: [128m]
  [dalvik.vm.heapstartsize]: [5m]
  [dalvik.vm.lockprof.threshold]: [500]
  [dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file]: [/data/anr/traces.txt]
  [debug.camcorder.disablemeta]: [1]
  [debug.composition.type]: [gpu]
  [debug.mdpcomp.logs]: [0]
  [debug.sf.hw]: [1]
  [gsm.current.phone-type]: [1]
  [gsm.sim.operator.alpha]: []
  [gsm.sim.operator.iso-country]: []
  [gsm.sim.operator.numeric]: []
  [gsm.version.ril-impl]: [Qualcomm RIL 1.0]
  [hwui.disable_vsync]: [true]
  [hwui.render_dirty_regions]: [false]
  [init.svc.adbd]: [running]
  [init.svc.akmd8975]: [running]
  [init.svc.bootanim]: [running]
  [init.svc.compcache]: [stopped]
  [init.svc.console]: [running]
  [init.svc.dbus]: [running]
  [init.svc.debuggerd]: [running]
  [init.svc.drm]: [running]
  [init.svc.hw_config]: [stopped]
  [init.svc.installd]: [running]
  [init.svc.keystore]: [running]
  [init.svc.media]: [running]
  [init.svc.netd]: [running]
  [init.svc.netmgrd]: [running]
  [init.svc.qmuxd]: [running]
  [init.svc.ril-daemon]: [running]
  [init.svc.servicemanager]: [running]
  [init.svc.surfaceflinger]: [running]
  [init.svc.ueventd]: [running]
  [init.svc.vold]: [running]
  [init.svc.zygote]: [running]
  [keyguard.no_require_sim]: [true]
  [net.bt.name]: [Android]
  [net.change]: [net.qtaguid_enabled]
  [net.hostname]: [sk17i-netzclub]
  [net.qtaguid_enabled]: [1]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.default]: [4096,87380,704512,4096,16384,110208]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.edge]: [4096,26280,35040,4096,16384,35040]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.evdo]: [4096,87380,563200,4096,16384,262144]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.evdo_b]: [4096,87380,704512,4096,16384,262144]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.gprs]: [4096,8760,11680,4096,8760,11680]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.hsdpa]: [4096,87380,704512,4096,16384,262144]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.hspa]: [4096,87380,704512,4096,16384,110208]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.hspap]: [4096,87380,1220608,4096,16384,393216]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.hsupa]: [4096,87380,704512,4096,16384,262144]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.lte]: [4096,87380,1220608,4096,16384,563200]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.umts]: [4096,87380,563200,4096,16384,110208]
  [net.tcp.buffersize.wifi]: [524288,1048576,2097152,262144,524288,1048576]
  [persist.chargemon.active]: [1]
  [persist.radio.adb_log_on]: [0]
  [persist.radio.net_pref_0]: [0]
  [persist.radio.nitz_lons_0_0]: [<CENSORED>]
  [persist.radio.nitz_plmn_0]: [<CENSORED>]
  [persist.radio.nitz_sons_0_0]: [<CENSORED>]
  [persist.radio.sma_voice_3gpp]: [0]
  [persist.ro.ril.sms_sync_sending]: [1]
  [persist.service.zram]: [18]
  [persist.sys.country]: [DE]
  [persist.sys.hdcp_checking]: [never]
  [persist.sys.language]: [de]
  [persist.sys.localevar]: []
  [persist.sys.profiler_ms]: [0]
  [persist.sys.purgeable_assets]: [1]
  [persist.sys.root_access]: [3]
  [persist.sys.strictmode.visual]: []
  [persist.sys.timezone]: [Europe/Berlin]
  [persist.sys.usb.config]: [mass_storage,adb]
  [persist.sys.use_dithering]: [0]
  [ril.ecclist]: [112,911,112]
  [rild.libargs]: [-d/dev/smd0]
  [rild.libpath]: [/system/lib/libril-qc-1.so]
  [ro.allow.mock.location]: [0]
  [ro.baseband]: [unknown]
  [ro.board.platform]: [msm7x30]
  [ro.boot.emmc]: [0]
  [ro.boot.hardware]: [semc]
  [ro.boot.serialno]: [BX902GVWR3]
  [ro.bootloader]: [unknown]
  [ro.bootmode]: [unknown]
  [ro.build.characteristics]: [default]
  [ro.build.date.utc]: [1370165795]
  [ro.build.date]: [Sun Jun  2 02:36:35 MST 2013]
  [ro.build.description]: [SK17i-user 4.0.4 4.1.B.0.587 tL1_3w test-keys]
  [ro.build.display.id]: [cm_mango-userdebug 4.1.2 JZO54K eng.M66B.20130602.023102 test-keys]
  [ro.build.fingerprint]: [SEMC/SK17i_1254-2184/SK17i:4.0.4/4.1.B.0.587/tL1_3w:user/release-keys]
  [ro.build.host]: [iof303]
  [ro.build.id]: [JZO54K]
  [ro.build.product]: [mango]
  [ro.build.tags]: [test-keys]
  [ro.build.type]: [userdebug]
  [ro.build.user]: [M66B]
  [ro.build.version.codename]: [REL]
  [ro.build.version.incremental]: [eng.M66B.20130602.023102]
  [ro.build.version.release]: [4.1.2]
  [ro.build.version.sdk]: [16]
  [ro.carrier]: [unknown]
  [ro.cm.device]: [mango]
  [ro.cm.version]: [10-20130602-UNOFFICIAL-mango]
  [ro.com.android.dataroaming]: [false]
  [ro.com.android.dateformat]: [MM-dd-yyyy]
  [ro.com.android.wifi-watchlist]: [GoogleGuest]
  [ro.com.google.clientidbase]: [android-google]
  [ro.com.google.locationfeatures]: [1]
  [ro.config.alarm_alert]: [Hassium.ogg]
  [ro.config.notification_sound]: [Deneb.ogg]
  [ro.config.ringtone]: [Orion.ogg]
  [ro.debuggable]: [1]
  [ro.emmc]: [0]
  [ro.factorytest]: [0]
  [ro.goo.developerid]: [M66B]
  [ro.goo.rom]: [Xtended]
  [ro.goo.version]: [1370165462]
  [ro.hardware]: [semc]
  [ro.hsdpa_cat]: [8]
  [ro.modversion]: [10-20130602-UNOFFICIAL-mango]
  [ro.opengles.version]: [131072]
  [ro.product.board]: [mogami]
  [ro.product.brand]: [SEMC]
  [ro.product.cpu.abi2]: [armeabi]
  [ro.product.cpu.abi]: [armeabi-v7a]
  [ro.product.device]: [mango]
  [ro.product.locale.language]: [en]
  [ro.product.locale.region]: [US]
  [ro.product.manufacturer]: [SEMC]
  [ro.product.model]: [Xperia Mini Pro]
  [ro.product.name]: [SK17i]
  [ro.revision]: [0]
  [ro.ril.def.agps.feature]: [1]
  [ro.ril.def.agps.mode]: [2]
  [ro.ril.gprsclass]: [10]
  [ro.ril.hsxpa]: [1]
  [ro.rommanager.developerid]: [cyanogenmod]
  [ro.secure]: [1]
  [ro.serialno]: [<CENSORED>]
  [ro.setupwizard.enterprise_mode]: [1]
  [ro.sf.lcd_density]: [160]
  [ro.telephony.call_ring.multiple]: [false]
  [ro.telephony.default_network]: [0]
  [ro.telephony.ril_class]: [SemcRIL]
  [ro.tethering.kb_disconnect]: [1]
  [ro.url.legal.android_privacy]: [http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html]
  [ro.url.legal]: [http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html]
  [ro.use_data_netmgrd]: [true]
  [ro.wifi.channels]: []
  [service.bootanim.exit]: [0]
  [sys.mem.max_hidden_apps]: [10]
  [sys.usb.config]: [mass_storage,adb]
  [sys.usb.state]: [mass_storage,adb]
  [system_init.startsurfaceflinger]: [0]
  [vold.post_fs_data_done]: [1]
  [wifi.interface]: [wlan0]
  [wifi.softap.interface]: [wlan0]
  [wifi.softapconcurrent.interface]: [wlan0]
  ```

## Update:

Now operating for over an hour (for copying files off the device via `adb`), the boot animation finished and the "log in"-screen (i.e, with the clock and the lock to wipe to the side to get access) appears, shortly for about a second, then disappers, black screen, after two seconds appears again, stays looping like that. Found out that it is the process `/system/bin/bootanimation` which stopped after a while. Same behaviour if killed by hand.

## Update 2:

There are a lot of files `/data/system/dropbox/system_server_crash@1460671235961.txt` (the numbers are timestamps and differ from file to file), a few per minute, all with the content

```
    Process: system_server
    Build: SEMC/SK17i_1254-2184/SK17i:4.0.4/4.1.B.0.587/tL1_3w:user/release-keys

    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
            at com.android.server.PowerManagerService$10.run(PowerManagerService.java:2839)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: Try the logs. In your case, I'd first check `adb logcat` (which you already did if I read that correctly), and then `adb dmesg`.

Comment: @lzzy: `logcat` (btw.: I run everything from the shell started with `adb shell`, if needed a root shell) gives _lot_ of output, not stopping. What should I look for? I am not familiar with all that android-specific stuff which is printed there. `dmesg` I'll try -- but the problem really does not look like a kernel problem, since I can connect to the device fine via USB cable and `adb`.

Comment: All those logs are ring buffers where's continuously written to, so naturally `logcat` won't stop. What I'd do is running it from the computer (root or not doesn't really matter), redirecting the output to a file, and then hitting Ctrl-C when I think I've captured enough (e.g. when the loop is "complete"). e.g.: `adb logcat -v time > debug.log`. And no, I don't have something specific in mind; I'd later grep the file for crashes and errors: stack traces are easy to identify, and error messages usually start with "E:", so one can filter (`-v time` adds a time-stamp to the start of each line).

Comment: @lzzy: Is there really only this way, via the spammed logcat? No way to stepwise boot?

Comment: Not that I know of. Check the help page for filter options to narrow down things in output (you might miss other details then) – or capture all and filter later. I'm not aware of a third variant .

Comment: android seems to complicated to debug in those cases. I now simply copy everything over by having mounted the device with `adbfs`, and then will wipe and re-install. The question seems to be left unanswered ...

Comment: Okay, there's a couple of reasons why this could be happening. 1. Are you using an official or unofficial CyanogenMod ROM?
2. If the lockscreen appears for a second, it means that some part of the system is crashing right after the lockscreen appears. You should be able to use Android Studio to filter debug output. (PS: I'd put a shorter version of this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: I am not anymore on that issue, since android is somewhat really confusing. Just a fresh re-install.